# How can I render a field inside a tpl.php that is hidden on the UI

Tags: taxonomy-terms, entities

I have a taxonomy field attached to a content type. On the teaser view mode, the field is hidden. I have two sections where I display the content type's teasers. On one section I don't want the terms to show. On the other section, I want them displayed.

I would like to know how I can render this field from the template **node.tpl.php**. It's not available as an element of `$content`, but is attached to the `$node` object.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add any markup or additional fields to the node teaser view or node full view using [hook_node_view()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.api.php/function/hook_node_view/7).
The following example is adding a taxonomy name to the teaser view.

```
function MYMODULE_node_view($node, $view_mode = 'full', $langcode = NULL) {
    if($view_mode == 'teaser'){
     $tname = db_query('SELECT name FROM {taxonomy_term_data} t WHERE tid = :tid', array(':tid'=>$node->field_category['und'][0]['tid']))->fetchField();     
     $node->content['my_taxonomy'] = array(     
        '#markup' => '<div>'.$tname.'</div>', 
        '#weight' => 10, 
      );
    }   
}
```

You would not need to update node.tpl.php.